# In FastAPI web application how to temporarily show users a message when something happens?

Tags: message, fastapi

I am developing a fastAPI web application, how to temporarily show users a message when something happens? I am looking for something similar to **flash** in Flask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I was also looking for something like that. I asked the same question on FastAPI Gitter. But no one gave any idea to solve the problem. I am sharing the snippet that worked for me. I have no idea it is production-ready or not.

**main.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from starlette.templating import Jinja2Templates
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
import typing

def flash(request: Request, message: typing.Any, category: str = "") -> None:
    if "_messages" not in request.session:
        request.session["_messages"] = []
    request.session["_messages"].append({"message": message, "category": category})


def get_flashed_messages(request: Request):
    print(request.session)
    return request.session.pop("_messages") if "_messages" in request.session else []

middleware = [
    Middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key='super-secret')
]
app = FastAPI(middleware=middleware)

app.mount("/static/", StaticFiles(directory='static', html=True), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
templates.env.globals['get_flashed_messages'] = get_flashed_messages


@app.get("/login/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_form(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/login/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login(request: Request, username: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    if username == "test" and password == "test":
        flash(request, "Login Successful", "success")
        return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request})
    flash(request, "Failed to login", "danger")
    return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request})
```

**login.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    {# Flashing message start here #}
            {% for message in get_flashed_messages(request) %}
                <div class="{{ message.category }}">{{ message.message }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
    {# Flashing message ends here #}
    <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" id=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```